# Why is my .minecraft directory empty? Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, games, minecraft

So, I want to install Minecraft Forge on my computer but it says this when I try to install the modloader

> There is no minecraft launcher profile at this location, you need to run the launcher first!

I'm a kid on Ubuntu and I'm a noob, so thanks in advance! also there is a problem when I run the launcher and get the bootstrap error on startup Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install vanilla Minecraft first, which means that you need to start the `Minecraft.jar` you can download from the Minecraft homepage after purchase.

You will most probably have a jar file. Do the following:

In terminal navigate to the place you have this file in (probably your Downloads folder) then do:

```
chmod 755 Minecraft.jar
cp Minecraft.jar ~/Desktop
```

After that you only need to find the file on your desktop and double click it. You can leave it there as an easy means to start Minecraft from this point on.

This will then create a folder in your home directory named .minecraft and will install the basic files after you've logged in. You should start Minecraft this way *at least once* before you start the forge installer `.jar` file with the following terminal commands after navigating to its download location:

```
chmod 755 forge-1.12.2-14.23.3.2655-installer.jar
java -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.3.2655-installer.jar
```

After the installer has run then you should start Minecraft again, at least till you reach the main menu.

---

**Addendum:** Minecraft needs Java 8 to run properly with Forge mod loader and most mod's. So open the Minecraft launcher and edit the forge profile in the following way (screenshot) after installing java 8 as a secondary java installation:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

Here is where you find the button for editing your profile:

[image]

And here is how you should edit it:

[image]

The line for the executable on 18.04 should contain the following:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

And the line for JVM arguments should be like this:

```
-Xmx2048M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

Of course your game directory will be in your home folder so you don't need to change anything there, but you need to decide which version of Minecraft you want to run but that's being set by forge.

Now you can end it again and put your mods into the `.minecraft/mods` folder.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78123/discussion-on-answer-by-videonauth-why-is-my-minecraft-directory-empty-ubuntu).